# Pyspark - How to avoid Broadcast Nested For Loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know how to avoid a broadcast nested for loop.
As this type of Join is not efficient how do you guys do to avoid it.

For example, by default, we'll have a broadcast nested for loop join with the following Join :

```
df.join(
    df_2,
    (df.col == df_2.col_a) | (df.col_1 == df_2.col_b),
    how='left'
)
```

How can I solve this simple use case ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
part1 = df.join(df_2,(df.col == df_2.col_a),how='left')
part2 = df.join(df_2,(df.col_1 == df_2.col_b),how='left')
resultDF = part1.unionByName(part2)
resultDF = resultDF.dropDuplicates()
```

Comment: This would work only with inner join.
If for a given row the condition is met on part2 but not on part1, an extra row would be found in the final result

Comment: You are correct, but that is handled by resultDF.dropDuplicates(), so no extra rows should be in the resultDF